# Python -> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'babel.numbers'

Tags: python, tkinter

He realizado una aplicacion en python3.7, con tkinter, al momento de codificar está todo correcto, funciona perfectamente, pero al hacerlo ejecutable con cx_freeze, en un apartado de mi aplicacion donde abro un calendario, salta el error.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Considero que hay que agregar algo más a la carpeta donde está el ejecutable, dado que antes de llegar a este punto tambien debi copiar algunos archivos más que no se agregaban con a la hora de hacer el build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualizacion: El problema consiste en que con el cx_freeze, no copia todos los archivos que necesiten, dado que cuando se creó el build, faltaba dos .dll "tcl86t.dll" "tk86t.dll", los cuales están dentro de la carpeta raiz de pythonX.X, y el problema que he postulado se soluciono copiando la carpeta babel de la ruta "\Python37\Lib\site-packages\babel" a la carpeta lib de donde se creo el ejcutable, reemplazando así la existente que tiene ausencia de archivos.